# how do I install libGLEW 1.5 for sfml 2.0?

Tags: c++, opengl, ubuntu, g++, sfml

I tried to install sfml 2.0 and indeed i'm still trying. I have a problem. When I compile it says: libGLEW.so.1.5, needed by sfml/lib/libsfml-graphics.so, not found

when I try to install it with command by typing sudo apt-get install libGLEW-dev
I get glew 1.9 which don't work and make me keep have the same error message. How do I get libGLEW.so.1.5 for sfml 2.0?

between I'm on a ubuntu based operating system~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this answer is probably only for amd64.
get the .deb package here(the second under "Downloadable files") https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/quantal/amd64/libglew1.5/1.5.7.is.1.5.2-1ubuntu4

(if it's 32 bit try downloading it here http://glew.sourceforge.net/ )

than double click it or type the folowing commands on your terminal:

cd folderwherethepackageis

sudo dpkg -i nameofthepackage

sorry if there is any english errors.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to create a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /dev/lib/libGLEW.so.1.9 /dev/lib/libGLEW.so.1.5
```